# HTTP over SSH, similar to SFTP

Tags: ssh, ssl

I have learnt about the following protocols.

1. SFTP - FTP over SSH (application layer)
2. FTPS - FTP over SSL (transport layer)
3. HTTPS - HTTP over SSL (transport layer)

Is there an SSH counterpart for HTTPS, like SFTP for FTPS?

I've heard about SHTTP, but -

1. It was referred to as an obsolete alternative to HTTPS (SFTP wasn't).
2. I don't know if (and I don't think) it has anything to do with SSH. I've seen it put with SSL instead.

If there IS one, why isn't it talked about as much as SFTP?

Answer (score 2):

> SFTP - FTP over SSH (application layer)
> FTPS - FTP over SSL (transport layer)

This is not accurate. While SFTP does file transfer over SSH and FTPS does file transfer over SSL the file transfer protocol itself is different. FTPS uses FTP as defined in RFC 959, i.e. FTPS is an extension to FTP. SFTP though is something completely different, i.e. it does not use FTP as claimed here.

> Is there an SSH counterpart for HTTPS, like SFTP for FTPS?

One could run plain HTTP over an SSH tunnel. This is from the standpoint of security about the same as running HTTP over SSL, i.e. HTTPS.

But it does not scale well, since traditionally SSH has used passwords and keys for authentication, where information needed to shared up front. HTTPS instead has used a public key infrastructure with certificate hierarchies from the beginning, where only a set of trusted root CA need to be shared and the trust into the leaf certificates of each server is derived from this.

Comment: "FTPS though is something completely different,". I think you mean SFTP in this sentence?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: you are right. I've fixed it. Thanks.